Avoid chakra ui floating label for Password Input
I am using
<FormLabel color={invalid ? 'secondary.400' : 'primary.400'}>{label}</FormLabel><Input type="password" />

from Chakra UI.
I want to avoid floating Label for password, and basically want to have same label, what other inputs have when I am using  and chakraui Input.
is there possibility to do it?
I tried to delete this FormLabel and try to create custom labe. but there should be way to make it simpler. if someone faced this issue before
